# How to get the raw string URL before attempting to getUri in UriInfo object?

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf

I'm making a request with a malformed URL from the client and want to rectify the problems serverside. Every function I call on the UriInfo object results in an error because it attempts to construct a faulty URI, which causes Apache CXF to go haywire.

I want the unmodified plain string to modify and send to my own server calls.